# Predicate logic from formula to English

Tags: predicate-logic

I study for an exam and I have this exercise that I've practiced

Let: Monkey(x) = "x is a monkey"

Likes(x, y) = "x likes y"

∃x (Monkey(x) ∧ ∀y(Monkey(y) ∧ x ̸= y ⇒ Likes(y, x)))

My response:

There exists someone to like all monkeys, but not all monkeys like every one.

I could use some feedback, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write

A=Monkey(x)

B=∀y(Monkey(y) ∧ x ̸= y ⇒ Likes(y, x))

We look at "∃x(A and B)". So there exists x such that A and B both holds.

By A, x is a monkey.

By B, we know the following fact: "if y is a monkey and y is not x, then y likes x".

As a conclusion, we obtain that:
"there is a monkey (let's call him x) such that every other monkey likes him (i.e. any monkey that is not x likes x) . "

Comment: thank you for the comment. could I interest you in having a look at this post as well?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918839/predicate-logic-translation-from-english-to-formula/3918854#3918854

Answer (score 0):

Propositional logic and its variable cousain, the predicate logic is **not** able to model all predicates in natural language, including that of English.

This is one motivation for higher order logic. And in fact, this is a form of set theory with one inaccessible cardinal. But as a language, it is more expressible.